# how can read a cookies file. In My system many cookies file alrady there

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpcookie

I am bit confused how can read a cookies file. I have try on google but have no proper solution. I have read this file but not success. `ckps_ws_weather_deg
cent
www.bbc.co.uk/
1600
4154368256
30363239
2133877056
30289814
*`
 this file is downloading bbc.co.uk server. thanks in advance.

snapshot is my cookies file......[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a great overview of [cookies in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). But to more directly answer your question, cookies that you manage (e.g. that you create) are **written like this**:

```
Response.Cookies["myCookie"].Value = "Hello, World!";
```

and then subsequently read like this:

```
var myCookie = Request.Cookies["myCookie"];
// if myCookie == null it doesn't exist
```

and further, deleting a cookie is a variant of modifying them. It's a little weird, but to get the browser to delete it you need to set its expiration to something earlier than today:

```
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("myCookie")
    {
        Expires = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)
    });
```

But, if you're needing to read third party cookies, and you're trying to do that via ASP.NET, you would need to perform a [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attack. There is a reason this is considered bad practice. This can be done via JavaScript, but I am not inclined to provide any code to do so because of its ethics.

## EDIT

The OP updated their question while I was answering, and I do still stand on the fact that the intent of reading third party cookies via a web application is **fishy** at best.

Comment: +1 for stopping short of giving bad advice.

Comment: sir have any link provide how to third party cookies read....

Comment: @j.s.banger, I'm not personally going to provide any links to show you how to read third party cookies from the browser. You can Google it from here. You know this much, it's a cross-site scripting attack and it leverages JavaScript. I'm not going to lead you any further than that.

Comment: thanks sir for valuable time...

Comment: sir can send me email coding ...plz this is my assignment 2marrow..